# Clarification for meaning of tags in chunking using opennlp.en - What does "O" tag mean?

Tags: nlp, opennlp, pos-tagger

I have found some useful resources for descriptions of what each chunk tag means. One that I am continuously struggling with is the "O" tag. It seems to be for punctuation and conjunctions, but I can't quite find a clear definition. Example:

```
"test and, that's all."
B-NP I-NP O B-NP B-VP B-NP O
```

what does "O" mean?

Answer (score 1):

Those are [IOB tags](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inside%E2%80%93outside%E2%80%93beginning_(tagging)) for a noun phrase (NP).

- `B` is for beginning, so `B-NP` is the first word in a noun phrase
- `I` means inside, so that covers other words in a phrase after the first
- `O` means outside, so it covers words that are not in a noun phrase